# Jquery Raty star-rating on Rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

The following line is generated by jquery in the DOM when a user clicks to make a 5 star rating:

```
<input type="hidden" name="review[answer01]" id="review_answer01" value="5">
```

Somehow my controller is not picking up this value for params[:review][:answer01]

It seems to me that when I click the submit button the hidden value isn't being sent at all. Is the form not aware of the hidden field because it's not present at the start? How do I fix this.

Everything worked fine with a simple radio button select.

BTW I manually added the same line of code to my form and it worked. I put

```
<%= f.hidden_field :answer01, :value => 5 %>
```

which produced html:

```
<input id="review_answer01" name="review[answer01]" type="hidden" value="5">
```

I just don't get it...

EDIT:

Here is the js source Here is the js: https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty/blob/master/js/jquery.raty.js

The input tags are generated by line 62, which I modded slightly to give an ID ( I wasn't sure if that was the issue ).

My line 62: `self.score = $('<input />', { type: 'hidden', name: self.opt.scoreName, id: self.opt.scoreId}).appendTo(self);`

I also added `scoreID : 'blank'` to `$.fn.raty.defaults {}` to provide an option to set ID.

Now, inside my view I have:

```
<table class='table'>
  <tbody>

  <%= simple_form_for @review, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

    <td style='width:115px; padding-top:10px;'><div id="s1"></td>
    <td><h3 style = 'padding-bottom:3px;'><%= @questions[0] %></h3></td>

    [...] (repeated for other questions)

  </tbody>
</table>

  <div style='margin-left:80px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:200px;' id='subbut'>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit Review", :class=>'btn btn-large' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

<script>
$('#s1').raty({
    scoreName : 'review[answer01]',
    scoreId : 'review_answer01'
});
</script>
```

What I see in firebug DOM analysis with 5/5 star selected:

```
<td style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;">
<div id="s1" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px; ">
  <img src="/assets/star-on.png" alt="1" title="bad">&nbsp;
  <img src="/assets/star-on.png" alt="2" title="poor">&nbsp;
  <img src="/assets/star-on.png" alt="3" title="regular">&nbsp;
  <img src="/assets/star-on.png" alt="4" title="good">&nbsp;
  <img src="/assets/star-on.png" alt="5" title="gorgeous">
  <input type="hidden" name="review[answer01]" id="review_answer01" value="5">
</div>
</td>
```

FORM TAG:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/reviews" class="simple_form new_review" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_review" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"></form>
```

Comment: That seems fine, could we have the JS that makes it and/or the surrounding form HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure isn't right... Look:

```
<table class='table'>
  <tbody>

  <%= simple_form_for @review, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

    <td style='width:115px; padding-top:10px;'><div id="s1"></td>
    <td><h3 style = 'padding-bottom:3px;'><%= @questions[0] %></h3></td>

    [...] (repeated for other questions)

  </tbody>
</table>

  <div style='margin-left:80px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:200px;' id='subbut'>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit Review", :class=>'btn btn-large' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

The `form` starts inside the table, but ends outside. this will cause the HTML to be parsed as not including all the `input`s and some general weirdness because the browser can't figure out what you meant.

Incidentally, using HAML would circumvent that kind of problems, but to each his own :)

Comment: Nice, I had another row outside of the form which semantically didn't belong there.. that's why the table started earlier. However, I now have it within the form, and everything works fine. Thanks Felix!

Comment: Well, to be a pedant, the table doesn't semantically belong anywhere near here :)

Comment: Aww, but the twitter bootstrap tables make forms look so GOOD!